# open set in tangentspace induces open set in tangentbundle (for homogeneous spaces)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homogeneous-spaces

Let $M=G/K$ be a homogeneous space with a $G$-invariant riemannian metric $<.,.>$.
Then $G$ defines an action on $TM$ by derivatives.

Let $p=eK \in M$. Assuming I have a set $V_p \subset T_pM$ such that $V_p$ is open in $T_pM$, w.r.t. to the scalarproduct $<.,.>_p$.

Maybe I did too much math today, that I can't find a way to prove it,
but is it now possible to find a subset $H \subset G$, such that $H.V_p$ is open in $TM$?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. Certainly, if $V_p$ is a $K$-invariant open subset in $T_pM$, then $G\cdot V_p$ is a $G$-invariant open subset in $TM$. But looking for the orbit of $V_p$ under a subset of $G$ sounds strange to me.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to say, that we need all of $G$. If it is true under the whole action, then I'm fine too, but I thought it is too restrictiv. Do we need, that $V_p$ is $K$-invariant? Because I showed that the map $\phi: G \times T_pM \to TM, \quad (g,v) \mapsto l_{g*}v$ (where $l_g$ is the action on $M$) is a submersion. And then it is an open map and so $\phi(G,V_p)$ is open in $TM$.

Comment: This sounds correct. But if you look at $\phi(G,V_p)\cap T_pM$, then this is not $V_p$ but the $K$-invariant hull of $V_p$, so it boils down to the same result.